# export actual documents from document tab not from files, attachments object

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, data-loader, dataloader.io

I have three documents(like image, pdf, word etc) in my documents tab(Please note: not on attachments, files object) and I need to export all the three to my local.
But when I tried to get that through data loader or dataloader.io I am getting only csv not the docs(image, pdf,word etc). May I know if it is possible to get or not possible to get. In data export also we don't have document object.
The reason for this requirement is, I need to upload all the documents from document object to files object.
Thank you.

Comment: If its a total of 3 documents, why don't you download each one individually then upload them as files manually?

Comment: Hi Shamina, for example I have mentioned three documents, but there will be many documents uploaded every day. on weekly basis I need to download the documents from documents tab and uploaded in files.

Answer (score 0):

If the migration needs to be done in same org then there is no need to download the files in the local, you can create a apex script to query the documents and create files on the basis of the data queried.

In case if there are lots of documents then you would need to run the script in batch

Also in case if you want to download the data in file format over your local that can't be done via dataloader or workbench as base 64 data can not be exported in to csv, you can use [dataloader.io](https://dataloader.io) to export the data as files but it comes with its limits on number of records you can export in free edition.
or
export the data in bulk xml via workbench and then convert base 64 xml to files via node js or via some local script

Comment: Hi Sumit, Yes, I wanted to migrate document(images, word) from documents tab to files in salesforce. Can you please provide if you have any apex script?